# Finding resource in dll instead of main application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll

I am working on a DLL that will place two hidden buttons in a WPF application.

Clicking those buttons on the right order will raise an event.

To remove the Mouse Over effect, I created a new style. I wanted the buttons to be completely transparent.

**WPF Code**

```
    SecretCode.WPF secretCode = new SecretCode.WPF(testGrid,  SecretCode.WPF.Location.Bottom, 75, 4000);
    secretCode.SecretCodeActivated += secretCode_SecretCodeActivated;
```

**APP.xaml**

```
 <Style x:Key="TransparentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border>
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, the issue is that I don't want to place that style on the WPF project as I want the DLL to be completely independent.

**Secret Code DLL**

```
public WPF(Grid grid, Location location, int size, int timeout)
{
    Button leftButton = new Button();
    leftButton.Width = size;
    leftButton.Height = size;
    leftButton.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
    leftButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    leftButton.VerticalAlignment = location == Location.Top? VerticalAlignment.Top : VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    leftButton.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    leftButton.Style = Application.Current.FindResource("TransparentStyle") as Style;
    leftButton.Click += leftPanel_Click;
    grid.Children.Add(leftButton);

    Button rightButton = new Button();
    rightButton.Width = size;
    rightButton.Height = size;
    rightButton.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
    rightButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
    rightButton.VerticalAlignment = location == Location.Top ? VerticalAlignment.Top : VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
    rightButton.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    rightButton.Style = Application.Current.FindResource("TransparentStyle") as Style;
    rightButton.Click += rightPanel_Click;
    grid.Children.Add(rightButton);

    timeoutTimer.Interval = timeout;
    timeoutTimer.Elapsed += timeoutTimer_Tick;
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If this is a custom control than just create the style in code

Comment: I didn't create a custom control, its a regular button, the only thing I did was change the style. However that might do the trick.. use a custom control instead, but that might a over kill.

Comment: The style is in another dll and button is in wpf exe? Why don' tyou use XAML and set the style using StaticResourceExtension?

Comment: The dll creates the button and returns it to the wpf to get it added to the interface. The only way I found to load the style resource was to place it in the wpf exe. I will check StaticResourceExtension, never used it before.

Comment: Update me if my answer helps

Comment: @Marcelo How the DLL creates the buttons? if by code then change the style template by code. If by XAML then change the style template by XAML. Show something about how the button is created and how it added to the WPF application.

Comment: I added all the code to make it easier. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcelo If you solved the issue, either post your answer for future googlers, or mark an answer here as the one you used to solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I could comeup with for you. Hope this helps.
Use the below string in your DLL class.

```
private string xamlText = "<Style xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" x:Key=\"TransparentStyle\" TargetType=\"Button\">" +
                                "<Setter Property=\"Template\">" +
                                   " <Setter.Value> " +
                                        "<ControlTemplate TargetType = \"Button\">" +
                                            "<Border>" +
                                                "<Border.Style>" +
                                                    "<Style TargetType=\"{x:Type Border}\">" +
                                                        "<Style.Triggers>" +
                                                            "<Trigger Property = \"IsMouseOver\" Value=\"True\">" +
                                                                "<Setter Property = \"Background\" Value=\"Transparent\"/>" +
                                                            "</Trigger>" +
                                                        "</Style.Triggers>" +
                                                    "</Style>" +
                                                "</Border.Style>" +
                                                "<Grid Background = \"Transparent\">" +
                                                    "<ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>" +
                                                "</Grid>" +
                                            "</Border>" +
                                        "</ControlTemplate>" +
                                    "</Setter.Value>" +
                                "</Setter>" +
                            "</Style>";
```

Add the following code at the top of the WPF method

```
var stringReader = new StringReader(xamlText);
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
var style = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Style;
```

Next, just do like so:

```
leftButton.Style = style;
```

and

```
rightButton.Style = style;
```

I had once an extreme case I had to use such method so I pulled it out.

Answer (score 1):

In some DLL:

```
<ResourceDictionary >
    <Style x:Key="BoringButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        //.....
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

On your application:

```
<Application  ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Globals;component/Styles/ButtonStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And then you can use it as a DynamicResource freely:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <Button style="{DynamicResource BoringButtonStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

An alternative way to the code in app.xaml is:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary(); 
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(dict, new System.Uri("/SomeAssembly;component/SomeResourceDictionary.xaml",System.UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I don't think you need a DynamicResource for that.. StaticResource will also just do fine I think

Comment: Also, @Marcelo, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx for more info regarding pack uris.

Comment: I would still need to add code to the WPF application App.xaml, I am trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you create a library, you define its setting set. These settings are specified through methods. However, you need to phrase your problem in the most general way you can. You need a way to set the pattern expected (the right order), a history member to check whether the pattern is being matched and styling/class attributes. You can store the settings into an ini file or an XML or into the memory of your program or under the hood inside the DLL.

Comment: How is this an answer to this question?